# multiple inputs in text box not totaling

Tags: vb.net

I got another super basic question, im trying to total the subtotals of every entry in the txtPrice.Text the user enters, and then refresh the other lables with the updated tax, shipping, and grand total.  Its not totaling the subTotal, everything else works fine.  Whats up with that?

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim sglSub As Single
    Dim sglTotal As Single
    Dim sglSalesTax As Single
    Const TAX_RATE As Single = 0.02
    Dim bytShippingCharge As SByte = 10
    Dim sglCompTotal As Single


    Single.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, sglSub)
    sglTotal += sglSub
    lblSubTotal.Text = sglTotal.ToString("C2")

    sglSalesTax = (sglTotal * TAX_RATE)

    lblTax.Text = sglSalesTax.ToString("C2")

    If sglTotal >= 100 Then
        bytShippingCharge = 0
    End If
    lblShipping.Text = bytShippingCharge.ToString("C2")
    sglCompTotal = (sglTotal + sglSalesTax + bytShippingCharge)
    lblTotal.Text = sglCompTotal.ToString("C2")
End Sub
```

Comment: `every entry in the txtPrice.Text the user enters` - I don't see anything that could handle multiple entries.  Looks like one entry and that's it.  Which variable are you refering to? sglSub?  The Decimal type would be more appropriate for financial calculations than Singles or Doubles.

Comment: i want the user to type an amount in the text box, and everytime the user clicks btnCalc it adds slgSub(the amount currently in the text box) to slgTotal.  Then using slgTotal, refresh lblTax lblShipping and lblTotal.

Comment: All the variables are only within the scope of the Calc method, so they all initialize to zero when you hit the calc button.  It *sounds like* you want to declare slgTotal at the form level: `Private slgTotal As Decimal`  (and yes, switch to decimals).

Comment: Which line does not yield expected result? Please use debugger to find out. Add this information to your question.

Comment: When dealing with money, always use `Decimal` rather than `Single` or `Double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tips
In this line:

```
sglTotal += sglSub
```

-Every time you work with a total initialize it to zero before adding a value to it. If not it can leads to undesired result.

-When working with currency is better to use a decimal type instead.

If you want a variable keeps its value declare it shared.

This a little example of how you can use a shared field

```
Public Class Form1
   Shared total As Decimal = 0D

   Shared Sub calc()
       total += 2
   End Sub


   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       calc()
       Label1.Text = total.ToString
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: whats the difference between declaring a variable shared and declaring a variable private at form level? Both of which work.

Comment: in this case none. A variable can't be declared shared as a local variable. It was just to let you know about its existence. So in this case just declare it at form level.

Comment: if you know how to deal with object oriented programming it's better te create a class or structure for your calculation.

Comment: you can declare a shared method to manage this calculation using shared field(the total you want). It will keep the value.

Comment: There is a difference if you have more than one instance of the same form.

Comment: yes but, in this case is only one instance, that's what i understood here, he just wants to keep the value of total. Every instance is a separate copy of its members. :)

Comment: ahhh thanks man, im gettin better at this one step at a time i guess :-)